# Can I have a Jersey ParamConverter for a List of PathSegments?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a data type that gets created from a `PathSegment` (I actually have a list of them), and I'd like to use something like a `ParamConverter` to do the binding, but it seems to only be able to convert from `String`, and there doesn't appear to be any way to have it convert from a `PathSegment`.

I know I can simply have Jersey inject the relevant `List<PathSegment>` and I can process it from there, but I am hoping to be able to use the same mechanism for binding to all the request values.

Does anyone know if Jersey supports this, and, if so, what the mechanism is to be able to bind against more than `String`s?